# startup script for multiprocess q

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to start up kdb with multiple processes to use to write scripts with KDB developer.
I understand that the processes that are set up need to be done so outside of the master process.

I have attempted to do this with a function in my .bashrc that creates 7 instances which are expecting a maximum of 8 processes. I then start up a final process with developer.
When I do this and try to connect, my OS informs developer that the connections are refused.
Could you advise on the correct way to start 8 processes to use with IPC in KDB?
This is my multiple process startup function in .bashrc:

```
mq() {
    echo "Spawning 7 q processes";
    q -s -8 -p 20001;
    q -s -8 -p 20002;
    q -s -8 -p 20003;
    q -s -8 -p 20004;
    q -s -8 -p 20005;
    q -s -8 -p 20006;
    q -s -8 -p 20007;
}
```

This is the code in .bashrc to start developer:

```
# Assumes user name is claude and opens Q with 8 threads. (to build separate processes use a negative number) 
alias q='rlwrap -r q -s -8'
# Developer set to open with 8 threads. (to build separate processes use a negative number)
alias developer='source /pathToDir/developer/config/config.profile; rlwrap -r q /pathToDir/developer/launcher.q_'
```

To start all this up, I open one terminal and type `mq` then open another terminal and type `developer`
Once in developer, I assign a handle to each process like this:
`{hopen("::",string[20000+x])}each 1+til 7`
Then the system tells me that the connection is refused.

How should I do this?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: "I understand that the processes that are set up need to be done so outside of the master process." Where does this constraint come from? Master process could just as easily spawn the processes itself.

Comment: Hi @user20349 - I tried but couldn't get it to work - other processes started up but they appeared to all just point back to a single extra integer (used by KDB to represent a process) which itself pointed back to the master. Peach was never more than twice as effective in testing.  and was advised by a colleague who knows more about KDB than me to try from an external bash script. Please also note I've corrected a careless cut and paste in my original question. (the bit where I connect to the ports that should be open with hopen). 
Keen for feedback if you know how to do this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use & when start multiple q processes in your shell script:

```
mq() {
            echo "Spawning 7 q processes";
                q -s -8 -p 20001 &
                    q -s -8 -p 20002 &
                        q -s -8 -p 20003 &
                            q -s -8 -p 20004 &
                                q -s -8 -p 20005 &
                                    q -s -8 -p 20006 &
                                        q -s -8 -p 20007 &
                                }
mq
```

Without &, only 1 process will be open at one time.
It work for me:
./mq.sh

```
bchen@homer:~$ ./mq.sh 
Spawning 7 q processes
q)q)q)q)q)q)
```

In q session:

```
q){hopen("::",string[20000+x])}each 1+til 7
4 5 6 7 8 9 10i
```

Comment: This has created a set of open processes. Strangely though, when I connect to them and send ".z.w", they all return the same integer 7). Also a standard Peach test seems to show minimal benefit from the extra cores:

```g:{sum y*exp x?1.0}
\ts g'[2#10000000;2 3]
\ts .[g;]peach flip(2#10000000;2 3)```

gives:
453 268436128
385 268436608

Comment: `Inside a .z.p* callback it returns the handle of the client session, not the current session.` You are getting the handle from the server process to your developer session with .z.w. Also that query is not going to have any benefit from secondaries as you only have 2 sets of params to send between 8 secondaries. Only 2 will be used. There is also a cost associated with serializing and deserializing between secondaries.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to q process, hopen should be used.
In a q session:

```
q){hopen("::",string[20000+x])}each 1+til 7
6 7 8 9 10 11 12i
```

It returns handles for each process.
We could make use of these handles to send commands for each process.

Comment: Apologies - sloppy cut and paste on my part. I had an equivalent to the above. (the statement I pasted in error was from an earlier attempt to start processes from within the main process. With your answer I still get the same result. I will correct my question above.